# Getting Context errors when creating a CRUD application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, crud, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a crud web app. I'm getting errors about the name space, which I can't figure out (sure it's something simple!) What does the type or namespace could not be found mean? It's only on pages related to the database. Or is there a way to link the sqlite database without a migration folder - ProjectContext file?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is ProjectContext your own class? Did you write it? Right click on it and click "Go To Definition. What namespace is it declared in?

Comment: If `ProjectContext` is not your own class then it can be from 3-rd party library. In such case you should reference external nuget/lib and/or add `using` statement. If you still need a help, then write what application are you trying to program. Do it by editing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class looks like it exists but in a different namespace to the one the controller is in. You will either need to provide a full refeerence to it's location:

```
Place1.Place2.ProjectContext
```

or a using statment at the top.

```
using Place1.Place2;
```

Visual studio has a shortcut to help you track down classes like this, right click on the problem class and click "Quick actions and Refactoring..." and you may be presented with an option to either insert a 'using' statement at the top or use a full reference.

[Quick actions and Refactoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/924Xy.png)